# XPC crash on bluetooth communication

Tags: ios, objective-c, xpc

I am developing an application that have a queue doing a long task.
     Several times, at the end (but not necessary) of this task, I got a crash in iOS with the following error :

```
iapd[125] <Warning>: Encountered an XPC error while communicating with backboardd: <error: 0x3dbc0744> { count = 1, contents =
      "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3dbc09dc> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
 }
```

But I have no idea about the reason for this error. The only thing i know is it's that come from a `segfault`, not from my app.

Anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it has to do with a pointer that has not been initialised or its pointing in the wrong place. Check your pointers and make sure everything is initialised before trying to do anything with them. A segfult means that you are accessing memory that you are not supposed to touch.